# What causes change of sex in certain monoecious plants such as Papaya?

Tags: botany, sexual-dimorphism

certain male flowering plants can be converted to female flowering and fruiting such as Papaya plants by just insertion of an iron nail in their/it's stem near it's roots? How can iron nail alter it genetically from male to female? Biochemically  what causes change in sex of plants from male to female?

Comment: Might be useful to provide more background or links to what you're talking about.

Comment: Please see edited 1... I've sited link to one similar observation, It's common gardening technique. When we plant papaya plant from seeds over ninty percent of plants are male. But when they grow to a desired height gardner either mercilessly prunes large number of leaves or inserts a iron nail in the stem near the roots. Most of the time this might result in conversion from male flowering plant to female flowering plant and fruits can be obtained. This technique may or may not work for other monoecious plants.

Comment: @user240988 please [edit] your question to include all necessary details instead of replying in comments. Comments are not searchable and can easily go unnoticed. Therefore the question body should be complete in itself.

Comment: @user240988 The scope of the question "What causes change in the sex of plants?" is too generalized. An answer can be provided for "What causes papaya trees to change sex from male to female?" But the phenomenon can not be generalized to "plants" as a whole, as most plants don't and/or can't change sex, nor is it bi-directional even in the case provided as an example. Can you be more specific in your question?